# how do I create a bounded return from mysql?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a list of users, there is a column 'points' and I need to create a list of the ten people with lower points and the ten people with higher points than the user.

The only trouble is I have no way of knowing at this stage what their points will be so I can't use hard values.

Help? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for more points then him

```
select * from users u
         where u.points > (select u2.points from users u2 where u2.id = ID_OF_THIS_USER)
         order by u.points ascending
         limit 10
```

and this for less points then him

```
select * from users u
         where u.points < (select u2.points from users u2 where u2.id = ID_OF_THIS_USER)
         order by u.points descending
         limit 10
```

As you can see you are getting specified user points number by subquery.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY points ASC LIMIT 10 UNION
SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY points DESC LIMIT 10
```

Comment: This one will not work as far as where clause is empty. Also it does not resolve the problem about specified user points number that question author presented.

Comment: UNION ALL should be used here as well, not just UNION

Comment: lord I must seem rude - thank you gentlemen, thank you very much indeed.